# Sum of sum of i^k using matrix exponentiation

Tags: algorithm, matrix, recurrence

> f(n) is defined as: f(n) = 1^k+2^k+3^k+...+n^k, so it is the sum
>   of the k-th power of all natural numbers up to n.
>
> In this problem you are about to compute,
>
> f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(n)
>
> 1 ≤ n ≤ 123,456,789 and 0 ≤ k ≤ 321

( Link to the original problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ASUMHARD/Matrix )

A naive algorithm, computing each term one by one runs too slow so I thought of trying to solve a reccurence relation.

Naive approach:

```
total = 0
for i = 1 to n:
    for j = 1 to i:
        total += j^k
return total
```

Exponentiation can be used to solve Linear Recurrence .
I know how to solve linear recurrences like :

```
f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + constant
```

But i couldn't find any information on how to solve recurrences like

```
f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + n^m
```

or

```
f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + n*m
```

or

```
f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + k^n
```

i.e. 
involving an 'n' term.

How can such recurrences be solved, or how to form the initial matrix whose power will be used to solve the recurrence? If not utilizing matrix exponentiation can someone at least describe an idea on how to approach it?

Comment: This seems more like a math question and not like a programming question.

Comment: Can you post the exact recurrence you're trying to solve?

Comment: This seems to be a math question rather than a programming question.

Comment: I also don't see, why you would want to use a matrix exponential for that question.

Comment: its a programming question on spoj. can u atleast describe the idea to approach

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried to edit the question as best I could. It seems somewhat arbitrary of you (plural) to put this one on hold when countless questions (many of them interesting) remain on SO where someone simply posts a naive algorithm and asks for improvement. The algorithm tag will always blur the line between mathematics and programming.

Comment: @MikeMB OP posted the question because he/she wanted help to learn. It's not unlike hundreds of interesting SO questions asking for improvement on a naive algorithm, which are almost always a "mathematical" more than a programming proposition. Why would you single this one out as "more about math," when the other questions are allowed to stand and be upvoted?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: First of all, I'm only seeing a very, very small fraction of the questions posted here. So it might well be, that there are a lot of similar questions on SO that I probably also would vote to close, if only I had seen them. So if anything, I didn't "single out" this one out of the pool of math questions, but I "singled this out" of questions, which I happened to read.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Now the OP didn't ask about how to improve his algorithm or cut down the runtime of his code (although this might have been the underlying motivation).  What he asked was how to **form** a matrix with a specific mathematical property. To make a simple example, where I personally draw the line: Asking *”how can I add two numbers in C++”* is a programming question, *”What is the result of 1+1”* is not.

Comment: @MikeMB I think you and others singled out this question because of it's format and presentation. There are virtually countless examples of SO questions with a naive algorithm (seems obvious in this case) and the OP asking for an O(n) or O(log n) improvement, which everybody seems happy about. There are also countless questions, which everybody seems happy about, where the answers present many varied solutions to the original problem and do not address "the question." I think that's great! That's how people learn and be creative.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: I can't speak for the others, but I stated my reason above, which had nothing to do with formatting or wording. My point is that the OP did NOT ask for an improvement of an algorithm or an efficient way to compute a matrix (at least not when I casted my vote). Now you changed the question and it can be reopened as a result, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84359/discussion-between-mikemb-and--).

Comment: @MikeMB Thanks for sharing your point of view. I think I just edited the question to state what was already stated implicitly, which is kind of my point - it was closed because of style rather than substance if we consider so many other naive algorithm questions where SO users can't wait to present more efficient solutions and nobody thinks of closing.

Comment: @גלעדברקן thanks for your support

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth why didn't you close this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663855/compute-series-without-being-able-to-store-values ? Just because the op posted code? The answer there is mathematical! I'm dismayed by what seem arbitrary choices by voters in your role.

Comment: @Barry why didn't you close this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663855/compute-series-without-being-able-to-store-values ? Just because the op posted code? The answer there is mathematical! I'm dismayed by what seem arbitrary choices by voters in your role.

Comment: @Petr why didn't you close this question: http://stack overblow.com/questions/31663855/compute-series-without-being-able-to-store-values ? Just because the op posted code? The answer there is mathematical! I'm dismayed by what seem arbitrary choices by voters in your role.

Comment: @j.a. why didn't you close this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663855/compute-series-without-being-able-to-store-values ? Just because the op posted code? The answer there is mathematical! I'm dismayed by what seem arbitrary choices by voters in your role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem [linked](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ASUMHARD/) in your question, we can use a series of mathematical identities (`S(p,k)` are [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)):

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

(3)

[image]

And finally, utilizing the identity,

[image]

we get:

(4)

[image]

Haskell code:

```hs
import Math.Combinat.Numbers

f n k
  | k == 0    = mod (div (n * (n + 1)) 2) 1234567891
  | otherwise = sum 
              $ map (\i -> stirling2nd k i 
                           * factorial i 
                           * binomial (n + 2) (i + 2) `mod` 1234567891) [1..k]

main = print (map (\(n,k) -> f n k) [(2,3),(10,3),(3,3),(100,0),(100,1),(123456789,321)])
```

Output:

```
*Main> main
[10,7942,46,5050,171700,193476340417]
(1.08 secs, 1374079760 bytes)
```

Comment: I cannot comment on whether your transformed formula are more efficient than a naive solution, but If it really took your program more than 1 second to calculate the solution to the example Input, it is WAY slower than a navie c++ approach (on my machine, the naive c++ version takes 1,3 **milli**seconds - but I don't hav a haskell compiler to test yours). Did you compile with enabled compiler optimizations? Btw.: You know, that the question was tagged with c++, not haskell?

Comment: Second, this might or might not be an excellent answer to the spoj question, but not to the OP's question (at least not to the original one without your edits) - at least I don't see any matrix here. But considering that this was more of a [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to begin with, I think that is fine.

Comment: @MikeMB I appreciate your engagement. Did your Naive c++ version compute the `sum of f(1,321) + f(2,321)...+ f(123456789,321)` in 1.3 milliseconds? I don't think so - that would be 7,620,789,436,823,655 operations (mine did, it's the last entry in my example output). And I think the OP did ask for other ideas, at least that's how I interpreted his/her comment, "can u atleast describe the idea to approach."

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the last one.