# Compute series without being able to store values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Problem statement[[here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/EC_SER/)]

> Let be S a infinite secuence of integers:
>
> S0 = a;
> S1 = b;
>
> Si = |Si-2 - Si-1| for all  i >= 2.
>
> You have two integers a and b. You must answer some queries about the n-th element in the sequence.(means print the nth number in the sequence i.e S(n) )
>
> **( 0 <=  a,b  <= 10^18),( 1 <= q <= 100000 )**

What I Tried(This would give a runtime error) :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long int q,a,b,arr[100002];/*Can't declare an array of required size */
 
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    scanf("%lld%lld",&a,&b);
    arr[0]=a,arr[1]=b;
    scanf("%d",&q);
    int p[100002];
    long long int m = -1;//stores max index asked
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&p[i]);
        m = (m>p[i])?m:p[i];
    }
    for(int i=2;i<=m;i++)//calculates series upto that index
    {
        arr[i]=abs(arr[i-1]-arr[i-2]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        printf("%lld\n",arr[p[i]]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Given : qi fits in 64 bit integer. since index can be very large and i cant declare that bit an array, how should i approach this problem(since brute force would give TLE). Thanks!

Comment: Don't statically allocate space for `p` and `arr` unless you really know their size, which apparently you don't know ahead of time. Use a dynamic c++ [container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) (e.g., vector, list, queue) to only store the values you need. Just push new elements as they are needed.

Comment: ok but how do i generate the series , because qi can be very large and in that case this would give a tle . for example this case :
`10^18 10^17`
`2`
`1000 10^15`

Comment: The series only requires you to know the last two entries Si-1 and Si-2. Only store those values as scalars and keep reusing those variables.

Comment: Don't push anything but q. This is an exercise in reading the instructions.

Comment: looks like @dpmcmlxxvi just figured it out.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually, it looks like he wants to store the value of the series at various places not just at the end. So, he has to push those values, just not all of them.

Comment: could you provide a pseudo-code ? i cant completely understand what you are trying to say .

Comment: @dpmcmlxxvi That's why you push the q values. They're the only values you need to test.

Comment: That assumes he only wants to perform a test when the value is calculated then forget it. The question is unclear as it reads "You must answer some queries about the n-th element in the sequence." If those queries are about, for example, comparing it to another entry then he'd need to store them.

Comment: @SarvagyaAgarwal Just store the values and update them after you've computed then new entry. `S2 = a; S1 = b; ... start loop ... S0 = abs(S1-S2); ... [Do something with S0] ... S2 = S1; S1 = S0;`

Comment: @dpmcmlxxvi you have me there, but his linked problem page just says print the suckers.

Comment: i edited the question . hope queries are clear now.

Comment: @user4581301 fair enough

Answer (score 4):

**HA!** There is a solution that doesn't require (complete) iteration:

Considering some values `Si` and `Sj`, where `i, j > 1`. Then, looking at how the numbers of the sequence are built (using the absolute value), we can conclude that both numbers are positive.

Then the absolute value of their difference is guaranteed to be less (or equal) than the larger of the two.

Assuming it is strictly less than the larger of the two, within the next two steps, the larger value of the original values will go "out of scope". From that we can conclude that in this case, the numbers of the sequence are getting smaller and smaller.

**(*)** If the difference is equal to the larger one, then the other number must have been `0`. In the next step, one of two things might happen:

a) The larger goes out of scope, then the next two numbers are the calculated difference (which is equal to the larger) and 0, which will yield again the larger value. Then we have the same situation as in ...

b) The zero goes out of scope. Then the next step will compute the difference between the larger and the calculated difference (which is equal to the larger), resulting in `0`. In the next step, this leads back to the original **(*)** situation.

Result: A repeating pattern of `L`, `L`, `0`, ...

Some examples:

```
3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...
1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...
3.5, 1, 2.5, 1.5, 1, .5, .5, 0, .5, .5, 0, ...
.1, 1, .9, .1, .8, .7, .1, .6, .5, .1, .4, .3, .1, .2, .1, .1, 0, ...
```

Applying that to the code: As soon as one value is `0`, no more iteration is required, the next two numbers will be the same as the previous, then there will be again a `0` and so on:

```
// A and B could also be negative, that wouldn't change the algorithm,
// but this way the implementation is easier
uint64_t sequence(uint64_t A, uint64_t B, size_t n) {
 if (n == 0) {
  return A;
 }
 uint64_t prev[2] = {A, B};
 for (size_t it = 1u; it < n; ++it) {
  uint64_t next =
    (prev[0] > prev[1]) ?
      (prev[0] - prev[1]) :
      (prev[1] - prev[0]);
  if (next == 0) {
   size_t remaining = n - it - 1;
   if (remaining % 3 == 0) {
    return 0;
   }
   return prev[0]; // same as prev[1]
  }
  prev[0] = prev[1];
  prev[1] = next;
 }
 return prev[1];
}
```

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/VlO5Gy) (play with the `a` and `b` values if you like).

If you have repeated queries for the same A and B, you could cache all values until `next == 0` in a `std::vector`, giving you really constant time for the following queries.

I'm also pretty sure that there's a pattern before the sequence reaches `0`, but I wasn't able to find it.

---

I just noticed that I missed that it should be the absolute value of the difference ...

If it's fast enough, here is an iterative version:

```
// deciding on a concrete type is hard ...
uint64_t sequence (uint64_t A, uint64_t B, uint64_t n) {
 if (n == 0) {
  return A;
 }
 uint64_t prev[2] = {A, B};
 for (auto it = 1u; it < n; ++it) {
  auto next =
    (prev[0] > prev[1]) ?
      (prev[0] - prev[1]) :
      (prev[1] - prev[0]);
  prev[0] = prev[1];
  prev[1] = next;
 }
 return prev[1];
}
```

As you see you don't need to store all values, only the last two numbers are needed to compute the next one.

If this isn't fast enough you could add memorisation: Store the pairs of `prev` values in an ordered `std::map` (mapping `n` to those pairs). You can then start from the entry with the next, lower value of `n` instead of from the beginning. Of course you need to manage that map then, too: Keep it small and filled with "useful" values.

---

This is not a programming problem, it's an algorithmic one. Let's look at the first numbers of that sequence:

```
a
b
a-b
b-(a-b) = 2b-a
(a-b)-(b-(a-b)) = 2(a-b)-b = 2a-3b
2b-a-(2a-3b) = 5b-3a
2a-3b-(5b-3a) = 5a-8b
...
```

Looking only at the absolute value of the coefficients shows ...

```
b: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 ...
a: (1) 0 1 1 2 3 5 ...
```

... that this is about the Fibonacci sequence. Then, there's also the sign, but this is pretty easy:

```
b: - + - + - ...
a: + - + - + ...
```

So the nth number in your sequence should be equal to

```
f(0) = a
f(n) = (-1)^n      * fib(n-1) * a +
       (-1)^(n-1)  * fib(n)   * b
```

Of course now we have to calculate the nth Fibonacci number, but fortunately there's already a solution for that:

```
fib(n) = (phi^n - chi^n) / (phi - chi)
   with
  phi = (1 + sqr(5)) / 2
  chi = 1 - phi
```

So, bringing that to code:

```
unsigned long fib(unsigned n) {
 double const phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;
 double const chi = 1 - phi;
 return (pow(phi, n) - pow(chi, n)) / (phi - chi);
}
long sequence (long A, long B, unsigned n) {
 if(n ==0) {
  return A;
 }
 auto part_a = fib(n-1) * A;
 auto part_b = fib (n) * B;
 return (n % 2 == 0) ? (part_a - part_b) : (part_b - part_a);
}
```

Some [live demo is here](http://ideone.com/cPBuLG), but this gets problematic when approaching larger numbers (I suspect the fib getting incorrect).

*The demo contains also the iterative version of the sequence, as control. If that's fast enough for you, use that instead. No need to store anything more than the last two numbers.*

To improve this further, you could use a lookup table with holes for the Fibonacci numbers, i.e. remembering every tenth (and their successor) number of the sequence.

Comment: You should round to the nearest integer, rather than truncate (assuming you have enough precision for that implementation to work).  It's surely better to use a double-and-add method for Fibonacci numbers rather than floating point multiplication, though.

Comment: @Hurkyl You mean for the fib function? It doesn't improve it in this case, I suspect the (result) value to overflow.

Comment: Dang. When I saw the answer I was hoping someone had a trick to get around the destructiveness of the absolute value and avoid the iteration. Great explanation of short-cutting Fibonacci.

Comment: @user4581301 Not completely, but almost no iteration is required. See my latest edit :)

Comment: @DanielJour Great answer. I just want to add that it is better to compute fib(n) using matrix exponentiation rather than explicit formula which can lead to some precision errors